# How to catch read error in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following problem, I'm parsing a file a use `read` to convert `Int` to `String`. The problem is when it fails, I have no way to display the string which fails to be parsed. I just get `Exception: Prelude.read : no parse`.

I tried to write my own `myRead` function which will use `read` and throw a more meaningful message but I don't know how to catch the error thrown by `read`.

Alternatively, is there any other way to find what's not been read properly (using debugger or trace ?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
case reads yourString of
  [(x,"")] -> correctlyParsed x
  _        -> errorHandling
```

otherwise, you can use `readMaybe :: Read a => String -> Maybe a` as follows

```
import Text.Read

case readMaybe yourString of
  Just x  -> correctlyParsed x
  Nothing -> errorHandling
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. However, in that case I'm lucky that `reads` exists, would that be possible to catch the error send by `read` ?

Comment: @mb14 You can only catch thrown errors in `IO`. `reads` etc. are more flexible since you can detect parse errors in pure code.

Comment: Indeed. In Haskell APIs throwing an error as `read` does, i.e. using partial functions, is considered by many a bad design. It's OK-ish for IO operations, but not for much else, IMHO.